# Finiteness of signed measure

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure and $|\nu|$ be its total variation. Then does $\nu \text{ finite } \implies |\nu| \text{ finite} $?  If so, why?

I can almost see this by appealing to the  Jordan decomposition of $\nu$ and the definition of $|\nu|$,
\begin{align*}
\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^- \\
|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^-
\end{align*}
but I am not completely sure that there can't be a measurable set $A$ such that $\nu(A) =0$  but $\nu^+(A) = \nu^-(A) = \infty$.

For instance, suppose our measurable space is $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ map a set to the number of integers it contains.  Then $\nu^+, \nu^-$ seem to be measures, and $\nu$ would seem to be a signed measure.  And if so, the implication of interest fails.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: An expression of the form "$\infty - \infty$" is not well defined. So for a decomposition to be well defined such an expressions may not occur (that's why your example won't work because your so constructed $\nu$ is not well-defined)

Then: Yes, your implication holds, moreover for a signed measure $\nu$ it's true that $$\nu \text{ finite} \iff |\nu| \text{ finite}$$

To see that consider Hahn's decomposition theorem which states the existence of a positive set $P$ and a disjoint negative set $N$ s.t. $\Omega = P \cup N$.

From this it follows that $$\nu^+(A) = \nu(A \cap P), \nu^{-}(A) = \nu(A \cap N)$$ holds for all measurable sets $A$ and it's easy to see that this implies  the equivalence above.

Comment: Very clear.  Thank you.